# AWS EC2 accessing on-premise storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-storage-gateway

Is it possible to have an application hosted on EC2 instance communicate with client's on-premise storage. Storage Gateway documentation only indicates the reverse where on-premise application communicates with AWS cloud storage

Comment: How is the on-premises storage being "exposed" such that the EC2 instance can access it? Is there a VPN or Direct Connect connection that links the Amazon VPC back to the on-premises network? Or is the storage publicly accessible on the Internet?

Comment: The on site-premise storage is not exposed public internet in any form or fashion.  There is no VPN or Direct connection to AWS VPC? Is Direct Connection of site to site VPC the answer? Thanks

Comment: You need some way to connect AWS with your on-premises network. Direct Connect is a permanent fiber connection. A VPN connection can go across your existing Internet link, but will compete for bandwidth with other users of your Internet connection. Once a network connection is in place, the Amazon EC2 instance would be able to connect with your on-premises network.